# Solr Cloud with a Dedicated Indexing node

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am setting up a 5 node solr cloud.
Is there any way we can configure one node for indexing and other 4 nodes for querying?

Or Any advise on how to achieve good search performance with incremental ingestion running in parallel.

Comment: what is the mode of querying and indexing? Sorlj or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up a node for indexing (as far as I know), but you can set up the indexer on a separate server. For this you need to use something like Solrj (There are plenty of solr clients in different programming languages to choose from. My index is written in python, and I use mysolr). Indexing this way also gives you more flexibility than using the DIH.